How to unit test MAUI app segment that uses the MainThread class
I am using xUnit to unit test my MAUI app.
I am testing my ViewModel class. The issue that I have is that a segment of code uses:
if (MainThread.IsMainThread)
{
    DoSomething();
}
else
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(DoSomething);
}

And xUnit is not able to use this code.
How would you go around that, ideally without having to specify special conditional symbols just for unit tests to run ? Is there a way to set up xUnit that I have missed ?
Note: here is the exception raised when such code is reached by code inside a xUnit project:

Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException:
'This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this
assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main
application project in order to reference the platform-specific
implementation.'


Usually, when you have dependencies that you can't control, either coming from the framework itself or from a 3rd party, you're not supposed to test them at all. If what you're attempting to test the DoSomething() method, a simple solution would be to introduce an interface and a wrapper class for the MainThread:
interface IMainThread
{
    bool IsMainThread {get;}
    void BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action action); // not sure about this signrature
}

class MainThreadWrapper : IMainThread
{
    public bool IsMainThread 
        => MainThread.IsMainThread;
    public void BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action action) 
        => MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action);
}

Then you inject that implementation to your testable class in the application, so your code looks like this:
if (_mainThread.IsMainThread)
{
    DoSomething();
}
else
{
    _mainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(DoSomething);
}

(_mainThread being an instance implementing the IMainThread interface)
and in your tests you inject a mock or a fake for that interface.

Currently writing unit tests for our MAUI Application.
Ran into this exact same issue, and as Zohar Peled mentioned, we ended up creating an interface for this. We replaced most BeginInvokeOnMainThread with the Dispatcher though. So we have an interface called IDispatcherService, that we inject into the VMs, then inside the service we have a few methods:
public interface IDispatcherService
{
    IDispatcherTimer CreateTimer();
    Task DispatchAsync(Action action);
    bool Dispatch(Action action);
}

Then we have the methods implemented ex:
public async Task DispatchAsync(Action action)
    {
        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(action);
    }

Following this approach, you can get  the same resuls as the other answer. The general idea is exactly the same.
calling this method can look like this:
await dispatcherService.DispatchAsync(async () =>
{
    await navigationService.NavigateTo<HomePage>();
});

